# Unable to login CPE's configuration page

Tags: networking

I have OUTDOOR WI-FI CPE installed by my ISP for internet connection.
Manufacturer: "Telenet systems" 
Model: "TWI 1040 - PE"

The specification on their website says it supports HTTP web based GUI management.

The ISP probably set it as bridge mode. So if i keep my IP as automatic (DHCP On) i cannot access CPE's configuration page. To solve this i assigned my LAN adapter static ip 192.168.0.x subnetmask 255.255.255.0 gateway 192.168.0.1

Now when i power up the CPE, i can detect the CPE at 192.168.0.254 for few seconds, then again it becomes inaccessible. & IP scanner/Port scanner can not detect it untill i restart CPE.

During the little time window, if i open http://192.168.0.254 i get a login page. the source code is given below.

```
<html>
<head>
<LINK REL="stylesheet" href="../styleSheet.css" type="text/css">
<script type = "text/javascript">

// Note: Like all Javascript password scripts, this is hopelessly insecure as the user can see 
//the valid usernames/passwords and the redirect url simply with View Source.  
// And the user can obtain another three tries simply by refreshing the page.  
//So do not use for anything serious!

var count = 2;
function showStatus()
{
    var vmesg = document.getElementById('99');
    vmesg.style.visibility="hidden";
    var mesg = vmesg.innerHTML;
    //alert(mesg)
//  mesg = mesg.replace(/(<BR>|<br>)+/g, '');

    mesg = mesg.replace(/(&nbsp;)+/g, '');
    //alert(mesg)   
    mesg = mesg.replace(/(&amp;)+/g, '');
    mesg = mesg.replace(/(nbsp)+/g, '');
    mesg = mesg.replace(/(<BR>|<br>)+/g, '@');
    //mesg = mesg.replace(/(N)+/g, '@');
    //mesg = mesg.replace(/(S)+/g, '@');
    //alert(mesg)
    var iwmesg=mesg.split("@");
//  alert(iwmesg)
    document.getElementById('2').innerHTML=iwmesg[0].split(":")[1];
//  document.getElementById('2').innerHTML=iwmesg[1].split(":")[1];

//  mesg = mesg.replace(/(N)+/g, '@');
    mesg = mesg.replace(/(=)+/g, '@');
//  alert(mesg)
    cwmesg=mesg.split("@");
    var cutcw=cwmesg[3];

    cutcw=cutcw.split("N");
//  document.getElementById('3').innerHTML=cwmesg[3].split("=")[1];
//  alert(cutcw)
    document.getElementById('3').innerHTML=cutcw[0];



    var mode = document.getElementById('16');
    var nmode = mode.innerHTML;
    nmode = nmode.replace(/(<BR>|<br>)+/g, '');
    mode.innerHTML = nmode;

}
function validate() {
var un = document.myform.username.value;
var pw = document.myform.pword.value;
var valid = false;

var unArray = ["root"];  // as many as you like - no comma after final entry
var pwArray = ["5up"];  // the corresponding passwords;

for (var i=0; i <unArray.length; i++) {
if ((un == unArray[i]) && (pw == pwArray[i])) {
valid = true;
break;
}
}

if (valid) {
  //alert ("Login was successful");
  //alert(window.location);
  //window.location = window.location+"/APStatus"
  //var loc = "http://192.168.0.11/login.html";
  var loc = window.location+"";
  var pos = loc.indexOf("cgi-bin");
  var newloc = loc.substr(0,pos)+"cgi-bin/start";
  //alert(newloc);
  window.location = newloc;
  return true;
}

var t = " tries";
if (count == 1) {t = " try"}

if (count >= 1) {
alert ("Invalid username and/or password.  You have " + count + t + " left.");
document.myform.username.value = "";
document.myform.pword.value = "";
setTimeout("document.myform.username.focus()", 25);
setTimeout("document.myform.username.select()", 25);
count --;
}

else {
alert ("Still incorrect! You have no more tries left!");
document.myform.username.value = "No more tries allowed!";
document.myform.pword.value = "";
document.myform.username.disabled = true;
document.myform.pword.disabled = true;
return false;
}

}


</script>
</head><body onload="showStatus()">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="20" >
<table id="apStatus" bgcolor="#33aaaa"  cellspacing=1 cellpadding=4>
<tr class="headerBLK2"><td>Station SSID:</td>
<td id="2"></td></tr>
<tr class="headerBLK2"><td>Signal Strength:</td>
<td id="3"></td></tr>
<tr class="headerBLK2"><tr class="headerBLK2"><td>Firmware Version</td>
<td id="16">1.2.8<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br></td></tr>
<tr><td id="9"></td></tr>
<table>

<br><br>
<table align="center">

<form METHOD=POST id="myform" action="start">
<tr>
<td>ENTER USER NAME</td><td> <input type="text" name="username"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td>ENTER PASSWORD</td><td><input type="password" name="pword"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td colspan=2 align="center"><input type="submit" value="LogIn" name="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</form>

</table>
<p hidden="hidden" id="99" class="hide">ath0&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspIEEE802.11g&nbspESSID:"An0kit-ss3ccA-Eth3r_CP3"&nbsp<br><br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspLinkQuality=72/94&nbspSignallevel=-69dBm&nbspNoiselevel=-95dBm<br><br><br><br></p>
<!--p hidden="hidden" id="99" class="hide">ath0&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspIEEE802.11g&nbspESSID:"An0kit-ss3ccA-Eth3r_CP3"&nbsp<br><br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspLinkQuality=85/94&nbspSignallevel=-65dBm&nbspNoiselevel=-95dBm<br><br><br><br></p-->
</body>
<html>
```

Obviously either the manufacturer has implemented the login page poorly or more likely my ISP has customized firmware of CPE.
If i enter username: "root" & password: "5up" i get nothing but the same page.

Why after power up CPE remains accessible for short time only.
and is there any method to log into this page.

Comment: Either case is likely.  Sadly, with either case, your options are limited.

Comment: Have you tried calling your ISP?

Comment: @DavidPostill  I want to tweak settings in CPE which my ISP won't allow me to do by myself. So that is not gonna help.

Comment: Heh, I like the note that the JS dev wrote. :)

Comment: Why was this scraped up from the bottomless pit of a database?

Answer (score -1):

You can find the web login to the router by following way.

1. Either SSH or telnet to system

   ssh root@192.168.0.254
   password: 5up
2. On prompt go to 
   cd /tmp
   cat .apcfg

In the file find 
    WUSERNAME=TikonaSUCPE
    WPASSWORD=***

use these credentials to login to the web

Answer (score -1):

i also had old "Telenet Systems" (used by, tikona isp) outdoor cpe lying around and i thought if i could use it as a repeater with my current wifi router or not. searched everywhere on the internet but only could find this thread related to it and useful. after tinkering a bit around finally i got it unlocked and use it as a repeater in bridge mode. jst though to share here and help the community. here's how!

> connect cpe with poe cable and another lan cable with ur pc.

> click reset button on cpe for few second till all lights blink.

> change ipv4 adrress 192.168.0.5 , gateway 192.168.0.1. by doing this u'll be able

to ping ur device @ 192.168.0.254 . opening this ip in browser will open the default cpe login page.

> if above two steps are done and u're able to access login page. move forward and download PUTTY.(an ssh and telnet client)

> in putty select ssh on port 22 and enter ip as 192.168.0.254 there and click open.terminal window will open asking for username.

> put username as "root". password as "5up". u'll be in.
> now in terminal window goto cd /tmp . u'll be inside tmp folder.

> write "ls -a" which will list all the files inside temp.

> write cat .apcfg , and find WUSERNAME=TikonaSUCPE WPASSWORD=1TaItTa^ItT1

> note the user name and pass above can be different in ur case.

> now login to gui with that usename and password.

> goto wlan config and put essid of the wifi that u want to connect .set station as wds station. selec wpa. mode wpa2, eap psk and put ur wifi password there in psk key. authentication as auto..

> now in network tab select cpe mode as routed , option 82 disabled and startup mode extender. system ip dhcp.

> now in ap scan tba pu ssid of the wifi that u want to connect .click scan .click results and select the wifi that u wanna and click connect. now goto overview and wait till the wlan status will be chnaged and u'll se ur connected wifi there. now reboot the cpe.

> after rebooting change ipv4 address as automatic and wait. after a while u can use internet.

> NOTE: if u can't browse. redo all steps of configuration and tinker with basic network configuration of network tab like cpe mode as bridged. etc.

if u have any problem can ask...[ss of username and pass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0e7C.png)

Comment: The original question is not about Tikona CPE:s. This doesn't even touch the question OP asked. This is a workflow on how you created a Wi-Fi bridge using Tikona CPE. Posting this here does not help the community, and since it's in no way related to the question, this will be deleted. I won't re-link the Help sections I provided on the other answer, but for the same reasons I suggest you delete this as well. The instruction may be helpful when someone asks help on creating Wi-Fi bridge using Tikona CPE.

Comment: The manufacturer "Telenet Systems" which the OP has asked for is/was used by the Tikona internet provider only.also the method that i posted will/should work with all the CpE's provided by Telenet systems. I hope now it's clear.